# Determine from JWT generated by Keycloak if a user is authorized to access specific resource

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, jwt, openid-connect, keycloak

[Keycloak docs on OpenID Connect](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.4/securing_apps/#openid-connect-2) states that

> The access token is digitally signed by the realm and contains access
> information (like user role mappings) **that the application can use to
> determine what resources the user is allowed to access on the
> application**.

Is it possible to determine from the access token returned by Keycloak after authentication what resources a user is allowed to access?
Following the [keycloak quickstart's instructions on Obtaining an OAuth2 Access Token](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-rest-springboot#obtaining-an-oauth2-access-token), i get the following JWT (with not relevant fields ommitted) :

```
{
  "aud": "app-authz-springboot",
  "sub": "9c6c4a66-bb14-420f-a8af-3b2771266b38",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "app-authz-springboot",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "user"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {},
  "preferred_username": "alice"
}
```

There's an empty field

> resource_access

Is there any way to fill it with the resources a user has access to? What's the specification of this field? Couldn't find it in [JWT RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.2) or [OpenID Connect Spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Claims)

I attempted another way that worked:

1. Obtaining the access token [using password credentials flow](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-rest-springboot#obtaining-an-oauth2-access-token)
2. [Exchanging the obtained token for rpt](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-rest-springboot#accessing-protected-resources-using-requesting-party-token-rpt) with slight
   modification adding *response_mode* argument:

   ```
   curl -v -X POST \
     http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/spring-boot-quickstart/protocol/openid-connect/token \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer "$access_token \
     --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket" \
     --data "audience=app-authz-rest-springboot" \
     --data "permission=Default Resource"
     --data "response_mode=decision"
   ```

However this solution requires dispatching 2 requests to Keycloak to determine if a user is allowed a specific resource.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage scenario is not clear. The standard mechanism to control access to specific resources is ***roles*** and you do get them as a part of the token. So if you configure access to your endpoints using appropriate roles model and assign required roles to the corresponging users, it will control the access. Actually this is the way access to the `/api/premium` URL is managed in the [SpringBoot example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-rest-springboot) that you referencing in your question (compare access by *alice* vs *jdoe*).

From your question as it is now, it is not clear why such approach doesn't work for you and why you want something else.